# DoTA 2 freeze when trying to open audio settings (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: sound, 18.04, games, steam

so I've a problem here. I've just install DoTA 2 through Steam today. Everythings is working no problem except for one thing. Every time I want to go to audio settings page, its just freeze. I know it's not a big problem because I still can playing the games but it's just bother me a lot. I really want to settings my microphone, speakers, music volume, and etc.

I don't think it's audio drivers problem since the games still having audio on. I really appreciate if you want to help me, Thanks!

## EDIT

Problems solved after i run the game via Terminal. I don't know why, since then my audio settings page can be accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to system settings and sound. Instead of going from dota open steam settings and change audio from there. You should get a screen like this ->[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i think it didn't solve my problem yet because i need more features that available in in-game audio settings page.

Comment: according to my expirience with dota 2 most of the setting are here in steam settings but im not sure why its freezing, you can send the log by opening steam using terminal.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it.

Comment: Hi, thanks mate! suddenly my problems fixed when i run game via terminal. Idk why, tho xD

Comment: then it might be a dota 2 having bug in the start menu shortcut but dota community have fast updates almost every week so hopefully that would be fixed, good to see your problem was fixed :)